# Is it legal to bring (or allow someone else to bring) a firearm on a private flight?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, far-91

Say that I want to leave the city and go hunting somewhere.  Is it legal to bring a hunting rifle and ammunition with me in a private airplane?

If yes, are there specific procedures to follow in order for it to be done safely?

Comment: My understanding is that the FAA takes no position on this, rather it's subject to local laws while you're on the ground.

Comment: I understand that Alaskan bushplanes ferry hunters around, most would bring hunting rifles, as long as they are stored correctly (unloaded) then I don't think they'll make a problem out of it

Comment: @ratchetfreak Alaska has a lot of strange rules/exceptions though so I'm not sure that I would use their procedures as evidence that something is legal in the rest of the US.

Comment: [Prepared Pilot points out](http://www.preparedpilot.com/info_pages.php?pages_id=7) that firearms have not been *required* by the state of Alaska since 9/27/2001. Previously, they were.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a tricky question, because it depends greatly on the laws of the locations you're flying to / from.  Here's a few of the things you have to take into consideration.

## Transporting is generally ok

---

[According to **18 U.S.C. 926A**:](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/USCODE-2011-title18/html/USCODE-2011-title18-partI-chap44-sec926A.htm)

> Notwithstanding any other provision of any law or any rule or
> regulation of a State or any political subdivision thereof, any person
> who is not otherwise prohibited by this chapter from transporting,
> shipping, or receiving a firearm **shall be entitled to transport a
> firearm** for any lawful purpose **from any place where he may lawfully
> possess** and carry such firearm **to any other place where he may
> lawfully possess** and carry such firearm if, during such transportation
> the firearm is **unloaded**, and **neither the firearm nor any ammunition
> being transported is readily accessible** or is directly accessible from
> the passenger compartment of such transporting vehicle: Provided, That
> in the case of a vehicle without a compartment separate from the
> driver's compartment the firearm or ammunition shall be contained in a
> locked container other than the glove compartment or console.

926A says nothing about the method of transport.  Most often it applies to motor vehicles, but it can just as easily apply to aircraft.  **Therefore as long as you're ok to carry at the departure airport and the destination airport, federal law protects you in between.**

**Also, remember that 926A only protects you if the firearm is unloaded and locked / inaccessible.**

## Ok, but can I bring my gun unloaded onto airport property, right?

---

#### Not in a sterile area

You can't take a firearm into the sterile area of an airport.  [49 CFR 1540.5 defines a sterile area](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr;sid=1ced5b69464d2621557bcad98c596051;rgn=div5;view=text;node=49:9.1.3.5.9;idno=49;cc=ecfr) as:

> Sterile area means a portion of an airport defined in the airport
> security program that provides passengers access to boarding aircraft
> and to which the access generally is controlled by TSA, or by an
> aircraft operator under part 1544 of this chapter or a foreign air
> carrier under part 1546 of this chapter, through the screening of
> persons and property.

So, if the terminal and the GA ramp are two separate entities, you're probably ok.  However, I've flown to some smaller airports where the GA ramp and the TSA terminal are right next to each other.  In these cases, you need to be careful that you don't get into the sterile area with your firearm.

#### Maybe not anywhere on the airport

Local law might prohibit the possession of a firearm anywhere on airport property, or the airport itself might ban firearms on their premises.  The only way to know is to check the specific airport you intend to fly out of.

## What if I want to carry loaded?

---

The first thing to remember if you carry loaded is that **18 USC 926A does not protect you**.  In that case, you're exercising the privileges of either open or concealed carry according to the laws of the departure and destination states.

#### Open carry

Some states prohibit open carry.  [Others allow open carry when unloaded](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQDJdurpUsA).  Others allow open carry when loaded.  Some require a permit.  Some don't.  Some only require a permit for handguns but not long guns.  If you're going to open carry (perhaps a hunting rifle on a sling), make sure that the local area allows this.

#### Concealed carry

Some locations prohibit concealed carry outright (to the best of my knowledge, you still can't carry concealed in Chicago, for example).  Other states allow concealed carry with a permit from either that state or [a state which they have reciprocity with](http://www.usacarry.com/concealed_carry_permit_reciprocity_maps.html).  So, for example, a Mississippi permit would be honored in Texas, but not in Nebraska.  Others allow concealed carry without a permit at all (that is, the [2nd Amendment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) is your permit).  First, be sure that your concealed permit has reciprocity with the destination state.

Even if you think you're open carrying, watch out.  **In some states, the act of being in a vehicle, no matter how visibly your firearm is displayed, makes it concealed carry.**  If you don't have a concealed carry permit, you may be in violation.

## Is there anything else waiting out there to bite me?

---

#### [Oh yes.](http://www.nraila.org/gun-laws/articles/2010/guide-to-the-interstate-transportation.aspx)

For example, Rhode Island.

> A Rhode Island carry permit is generally required to
> transport a handgun in a vehicle. This requirement does not apply,
> however, to the holder of an out-of-state carry permit who intends to
> travel uninterrupted through the state.

Is a fuel stop an "interruption"?

Or New Jersey.

> [New Jersey] State law generally prohibits any person from knowingly possessing or
> transporting any rifle or shotgun without first having obtained a New
> Jersey firearms purchaser identification card (FPIC),or from
> possessing or transporting any handgun without first having obtained a
> New Jersey handgun carry permit.

Or Chicago.

> Chicago, for example, bans handguns declared “unsafe” by the
> Superintendent of the Department of Police, so-called “assault
> weapons,” machine guns and other firearms regulated under the National
> Firearms Act, “laser sight accessories,” firearm silencers or
> “mufflers,” “high-capacity” (i.e., more than 12-round) magazines, and
> “metal piercing bullets” (which include ammunition with non-lead
> projectiles).  All these items are subject to seizure and forfeiture.
> In some cases, the local ordinances have no explicit exceptions to
> these bans for travelers merely passing through the jurisdiction

Or New York City.

> Possession of a handgun within New York City requires a New York City
> handgun license or a special permit from the city police commissioner
> validating a state license within the city. Even New York state
> licenses are generally not valid within New York City unless a
> specific exemption applies, such as when the New York City police
> commissioner has issued a special permit to the licensee or “the
> firearms covered by such license are being transported by the licensee
> in a locked container and the trip through the city of New York is
> continuous and uninterrupted.”

---

## Look, just tell me what to do.

Fine.

- Carry your firearms unloaded, locked, and inaccessible.
- Make as few intermediate stops as possible
- Know and comply with all local laws both at your departure and your destination
- Stay out of sterile areas while armed on airport property

Comment: So I can carry a loaded gun as PIC if it is legal (either open or concealed) in the state that I'm flying in?